# j2me https connection without having root certificate

Tags: java-me, https

I am developing a javame application that connects to a web server which has verisign certificate installed.
Is there a way to implement https connection to connect this server? If bouncycastle is the way, is there any example?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to bother because:

"MIDP 2.0 adds a robust end-to-end security model, built on open standards, that protects the network, applications and mobile information devices. MIDP 2.0 supports HTTPS and leverages existing standards such as SSL and WTLS to enable the transmission of encrypted data."

From http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whatsnew-138562.html#endtoend

Also, see this nice video on how SSL works: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJJmoDZ3il8